# GCC Errors When Building Example Program From SDL Tutorial

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to build this example program dots.c from an old SDL tutorial here. http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/64143-game-programming-in-linux-for-windows-programmers-part-2/ I'm getting errors from GCC which I think may be related to missing C escape sequences which were omitted either by my copy-pasting or the original HTML representation. But I don't know enough about C to say one way or the other. I'd like to know what changes the code needs to clear these build errors, ideally with how you identified those. Thank you.

```
dots.c:41:94: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘/’ token
 void set_sdl_pixel(SDL_PixelFormat *what,void *pixel,int width,int x,int y,int r,int g,int B)/>
                                                                                              ^
dots.c:66:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
dots.c:91:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
dots.c:113:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
dots.c:132:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
 {
 ^
dots.c:163:1: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input
 }
 ^
```

40-42

```
/* Sets a pixel in a surface, paying attention to pixel format */
void set_sdl_pixel(SDL_PixelFormat *what,void *pixel,int width,int x,int y,int r,int g,int B)/>
{
```

64-66

```
/* Draws things using direct access to the surface */
void draw_pixels(SDL_Surface *screen)
{
```

89-91

```
/* Initializes the game */
void game_init()
{
```

111-113

```
/* Processes everything in the game for a frame */
void game_main()
{
```

130-132

```
/* Main */
int main()
{
```

158-163

```
    }
    /* Exit SDL */
    SDL_Quit();
    /* Exit */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whats the `/>` for?

Comment: I deleted that, and the rest of the errors changed to three more />'s in that same paragraph instead. We're running now. Thank you.

Comment: Please make an answer or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

There was stray HTML in the tutorial code in the form of />'s on lines 41,51, 55, 59. These had to be deleted before GCC would successfully build. Thanks to tkausl for suggesting the solution.